# How can I use the StartApp SDK integrated in Titanium?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, startapp

I am a new app developer, I am using Titanium Studio to create my apps and I want to integrate StartApp framework into my apps. But the StartApp integration uses Java which i cant write in titanium, 
is there any possible way to integrate it with titanium?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to use the AppStart framework in Titanium dircetly. In Titanium you can only integrate Titanium-moduls which can be found in the [marketplace](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/home). If there is no module which fits your needs then you can write your own module. It is also possible to wrap java in these modules (e.g. the [TiTouchImageView module](https://github.com/iotashan/TiTouchImageView/) wraps an Android specific imageView).

Answer (score 0):

You can develop custom native module for both Android (using java) or iOS (using objective-c). You can leverage your java skills to write what you need.

I don't know exactly what StartApp is, but my guess is that if you can intergrate it with regular java code for Android, you can also do it with a module. The entire Titanium SDK is built on the same concept of modules. The Titanium Marketplace is all modules developed by developers just like you.

You can find more information about developing Native Titamium Modules for Android here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide